# Drag gestures inside scrollable control

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've made a custom control based around a Canvas. It uses two `.pointerInput` modifiers, one to detect click and one to detect drag so the user can toggle a column of 50 buttons, either by clicking on one at a time or dragging across a number of them to set them all at once. It works well, and now I'd like to have a horizontally scrollable Row containing a number of these. The immediate problem is that the Row, when the `.horizontalScroll` modifier is applied, swallows vertical movement as well, and even taps, so although I can scroll through a number of controls I'm no longer able to interact with them.

The only example I can find that's similar is the nested scrolling in the [Gestures](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#auto-nested-scrolling) documentation, but that's between two controls using scrolling, and although the outer control is clearly not preventing the inner control receiving events it's not clear how to apply it in my case.

Without pasting huge quantities of code, I'm defining the Row by

```
@Composable
fun ScrollBoxes() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        repeat(20) {
            Column {
                Text(
                    "Item $it", modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(2.dp)
                        .width(500.dp)
                )
                JetwashSlide(
                    model = JetwashSlideViewModel()
                )
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

and the modifier of the Canvas is my custom control is set up as

```
modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures(
                onDragStart = { ... }

                },
                onDragEnd = { ... },
                onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consumeAllChanges();
                    ...
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onPress = { it ->
                    ...
                }
            )
        }
```

A crude approach would be to have a scrollable row of labels and use the presently selected label to determine which full width custom control is presently visible. This wouldn't be as aesthetically pleasing as having the controls scrolling horizontally. Does anyone have an idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: Have same problem with `HorizontalPager` and inner zoomable item with 
`detectTransformGestures` where the swipe was intercepted by `detectTransformGestures` and `HorizontalPager` does not swipe anymore. Did you find any solution for your use case?

Comment: @RogerRV this prompted me to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my starting point was this tutorial on how to make a scrolling pager from scratch;

https://fvilarino.medium.com/creating-a-viewpager-in-jetpack-compose-332d6a9181a5

Using that, you can get a horizontally scrolling row of instances of a control. The problem is that I wanted horizontal swipes to be handled by the pager, and taps and vertical swipes to be handled by the custom control, and although the custom control gets the gestures if made over the control, it couldn't pass them up to the pager if they were horizontal swipes, so you could only scroll using the gaps between the custom controls. I expected that the control could use .detectVerticalDragGestures and .detectTapGestures and the pager could use .detectHorizontalDragGestures, but it wasn't that simple.

I ended up pulling code from the Jetpack source into my own code so I could modify it to produce my own gesture detector which captures vertical scroll and tap events but does not capture horizontal scroll;

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectVerticalDragOrTapGestures(
    onDragStart: (Offset) -> Unit = { },
    onDragEnd: () -> Unit = { },
    onDragCancel: () -> Unit = { },
    onVerticalDrag: (change: PointerInputChange, dragAmount: Float) -> Unit,
    onClick: ((Offset) -> Unit) = { },
    model: JetwashSlideViewModel
) {
    forEachGesture {
        awaitPointerEventScope {
            model.inhibitGesture = false
            val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
            //val drag = awaitVerticalTouchSlopOrCancellation(down.id, onVerticalDrag)
            val drag = awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation(
                down.id
            ) { change: PointerInputChange, dragAmount: Offset ->
                if (abs(dragAmount.y) > abs(dragAmount.x)) {
                    //This is a real swipe down the slide
                    change.consumeAllChanges()
                    onVerticalDrag(change, dragAmount.y)

                }
            }

            if (model.inhibitGesture) {
                onDragCancel()
            } else {
                if (drag != null) {
                    onDragStart.invoke(drag.position)
                    if (
                        verticalDrag(drag.id) {
                            onVerticalDrag(it, it.positionChange().y)
                        }
                    ) {
                        onDragEnd()
                    } else {
                        onDragCancel()
                    }
                } else {
                    //click.
                    if (!model.inhibitGesture)
                        onClick(down.position)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now in the pager, it was using `.horizontalDrag`. This is fine if you can actually drag purely horizontally or purely vertically, but you can't and swipes that were intended to be vertical on the inner control often had a tiny bit of horizontal motion which caused the pager to intercept it. So in the pager, I also had to copy and modify some code to make my own .horizontalDrag;

```
suspend fun AwaitPointerEventScope.horizontalDrag(
    pointerId: PointerId,
    onDrag: (PointerInputChange) -> Unit
): Boolean = drag(
    pointerId = pointerId,
    onDrag = onDrag,
    motionFromChange = { if (abs(it.positionChangeIgnoreConsumed().x) > 10) it.positionChangeIgnoreConsumed().x else 0f },
    motionConsumed = { it.positionChangeConsumed() }
)
```

This only triggers if the horizontal component of the movement is larger than 10px.

Finally, since a horizontal scroll may also have some element of vertical which could affect the inner controls, in my `onPagerScrollStart` and `onPagerScrollFinished` callbacks I set and clear a flag in the model, `inhibitGesture` which causes the inner control to disregard gestures that it happens to get while the pager is in the process of being scrolled.